# Why Completion Suggester in Elastic Search with Edge Ngram analyzer takes 15 to 17 times more index size as compared to default

Tags: elasticsearch

I am implementing **completion suggester** on **multiple field** having alphanumeric and colon(**AA:890090:xyz:9090**). 
When I use **default analyzer** for completion suggester(simple analyzer), I am not able to get suggestions(AA:890) as simple analyzer **tokenize alphabets only**.
To overcome this issue, we used **edge ngram analyzer**, which solves the suggestion issues but index size is more than **15 to 17 times** as compared to default analyzer.
Foreg. index size is around **3GB with default analyzer** and **with ngram analyzer size become 50 GB**.

Why index size with ngram analyzer is **that much high** as compare to default analyzer, **Elastic search mapping** can be find below.
Please suggest, if there is any better way to do the same.

Sample data:
AA:890090:xyz:9090

Sample Mapping :

```
 {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "ngram_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 40
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "ngram_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "ngram_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "field1Suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "whitespace"
        },
        "field2Suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the analyze endpoint to see what happens. The amount of terms when entering the content of multiple words increases immensely. The following lines can already create 12 terms.

```
POST /posts/_analyze
{
  "explain": true,
  "field": "field1Suggest",
  "text": "green yellow red"
}
```

Output gives you these terms:

```
gre yel red
gre yell red
gre yello red
gre yellow red
gree yel red
gree yell red
gree yello red
gree yellow red
green yel red
green yell red
green yello red
green yellow red
```